# Ansible not able to find host from inventory

Tags: ansible

I am trying to run a playbook on a selective host after it has been provisioned using earlier set of tasks

I am able to ping the host and the same is available in the `/etc/ansible/hosts` file however the play says `skipping: no hosts matched` and does not run.

Ansible hosts file looks like below

```
vm1  ansible_host=192.168.200.52
```

I have tried mentioning the inventory file using -i with no success, what could be wrong here ?

**UPDATE**: Added the `/etc/ansible/hosts` as default inventory however the playbook still says its not able to see the VM

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Ansible hosts file looks like below

```
vm1  ansible_host=192.168.200.52
```

> Q: *"I have tried mentioning the inventory file using -i with no success, what could be wrong here?"*

A: To see what's wrong run the command below

```
$ ansible-inventory -i hosts --list
```

The output should give

```
{
    "_meta": {
        "hostvars": {
            "vm1": {
                "ansible_host": "192.168.200.52"
            }
        }
    }, 
    "all": {
        "children": [
            "ungrouped"
        ]
    }, 
    "ungrouped": {
        "hosts": [
            "vm1"
        ]
    }
}
```

A simple playbook

```
- hosts: vm1
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_host
```

should give

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yml
...
ok: [vm1] => {
    "ansible_host": "192.168.200.52"
```

Comment: Mine gives a bit different output, not sure why its paring `/home/neon/scripts/ansible/virtualbox/hosts`. I am trying to use default `/etc/ansible/hosts` for inventory items

`[WARNING]: Unable to parse /home/neon/scripts/ansible/virtualbox/hosts as an inventory source

[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available

{
"_meta": {
"hostvars": {}
},
"all": {
"children": [
"ungrouped"
]
}
}`

Comment: I see. You are in the right direction to find out what could be wrong here.

Comment: Unfortunately, i am still stuck. Updated the question with more details